# An accumulation point of $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ is an accumulation point of at least one $A_i$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A_1,A_2,\dots, A_n$ be sets in $\mathbb{R}^p$ and let $a$ be an accumulation point of $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$. Show that $a$ is an accumulation point of at least one of the sets $A_i$.

**My attempt:**

We denote the set of accumulation points of $A$ by $A^\prime$.

Let $a \in \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \right)^\prime$. Then $B^\prime (a,r)\cap\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \neq \emptyset$ for every $r>0$.

Now we must have that $B^\prime (a,r)\cap A_i \neq \emptyset$ for at least one $A_i$ (from the definition of union) and hence $a \in A_i ^\prime$ for at least one $i$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose now that $a \not \in A_i'$ for any $i$.  That means there exists a radius $r_i$ such that $B^\prime(a, r_i) \cap A_i$ contains only finitely many points.  Take the smallest of these radii and then you have that $B^\prime(a, r_{\min})$ contains only finitely many points of $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$.

Comment: I updated the question with something different. Is that which I have now also correct? Or not? :)

Comment: Contradiction certainly does illustrate the point more clearly :). Thank you!

Comment: @Mnifldz I can see hiw your proof works, but are you sure OP's proof is correct? In principle the chosen $A_i$ depends on $r$, doesn't it?

Comment: @GPerez I think you're right actually.  It is a bit of a jump to conclude that a limit point of the union must be a limit point of one of the sets.